# Why are Managed Metadata Default Values not working in Modern View?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2019

We are having an issue in our SharePoint 2019 farm which I have replicated on multiple farms including my own.

The farms are patched at various levels, including one on the latest CU (Feb 2020).

The issue relates to default values on Managed Metadata Site Columns with Lists in Modern View.

This is the reproduction scenario:

1. Create a Managed Metadata Site Column "ColA" with any Term Store, make it mandatory and give it a default value.
2. Assign it to a custom Content Type "CT1", and then assign "CT1" to a List (not Library) and remove the built in "Item" type.

Then, when creating a new item, the default value will not populate when creating in Modern View with the "+ New" button.

If I create an item via Classic View or Quick Edit, the default value is populated, but in Modern View it is not.

Any advice or experience with this or similar issue would be good, we have other issues that seem to be related to Managed Metadata too.

Has anyone else had this issue (or similar) and could provide ideas?

P.S. First post, be gentle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue on my SharePoint 2019 farm. The default value of the managed metadata column would not be displayed when new item.

Also, I find something interesting: I do not make the column mandatory, but give it a default value. When creating a new item, I leave the managed metadata column blank and click save. The managed metadata column of the new item would have the default value.

It seems to be a bug in SharePoint 2019. I would suggest you submit your feedback through uservoice: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thank you for the research. Sadly for me, these columns have to be mandatory as they are capturing information required by policy. I make it easier for users by providing the default value which is right 90%+ of the time but they are having to fill it in themselves and not only is it very annoying for them (there's several fields) but they make mistakes. I'll wait and see if anyone else has an idea but yes it seems like a bug. :(

Comment: Whilst I may add something to uservoice, that is for new ideas/suggestions, not clear defects. I have also found a way to consistently break SharePoint Online with Managed Metadata, it's actually riddled with issues. I will close this question now as it's clearly a defect.